# Does bzip2 creates an output file even if the command was interrupted/canceled while in progress?

Tags: unix, compression, bzip2

I was logged in via SSH to a remote machine and compressing a single 90GB XML file there using:

```
bzip2 myfile.xml
```

My connection timed out, so I am not sure whether bzip2 worked, but I ended up with an output file **myfile.xml.bz2**.

**When a bzip2 command fails to fully execute, does it save an output file or not?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more appropriate question would be whether it cleans up after itself.

BZip2 compresses data in relatively small blocks, and outputs each block before it proceeds to the next one. This [allows it to run](http://www.bzip.org/1.0.3/html/memory-management.html) on memory-constrained systems and still process practical amounts of data (it needs less than 8MB RAM to handle even that 90 GB XML of yours).

If you inspect the source file `bzip2.c`, you can notice that it does clean up in function `void cleanUpAndFail(Int32 ec)`, assuming the input file still exists. Of course, if the program got killed before it could run to completion, it wouldn't be able to do that.

---

In your case, if `myfile.xml` still exists and you didn't explicitly tell bzip2 to keep it (seems you didn't), then `bzip2` likely got killed before completing. If it's gone, then it likely completed without issues. You could use `bzip2 -tv` to run an integrity test on it.